# How to get get Output of SQL query in a flat file using shell script

Tags: sql, linux, shell, unix

I want to automate the a SQL file which contains multiple SQL queries using shell script and in the same time I want to get the **Output** of the **last Query** from that SQl file into any flat file.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` command will find the last semicolon-separated query in the file and pipe it to `mysql`

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=";"} NF > 0 {query=$0; } END {print query}' file.sql | mysql -u username -p password > output.txt
```

The `NF > 0` keeps it from setting `query` to the empty line after the last `;`.

Comment: Sql Query is in multiple lines , with ";" at the end of each query, something like this

Comment: If I got it right, all queries are to be executed not just the last one.

Comment: `select 
count (*)
from custcomps
group by 1
having count(*) >  50
;

select count ( unique(Siebel_Ac_No))
from custcomps
;

show select *
from custcomps
;

select *
from "EDWPRDE_VW40_OLAP_CMPLNT"."SR_STTS_TYPE_DIM" 

show
select PIH."Party_Idntn_Num"
from EDWPRDE_VW40_OLAP_CMPLNT.CMPLNT_DTL CMPS
inner join EDWPRDE_VW40_PUB.T01005_Party_IDNTN_HIST PIH
on PIH.Party_Id = CMPS."Customer Id"
and PIH.Party_Idntn_Type_Id = 2
and PIH.Party_Idntn_End_Dttm = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
where CMPS."As-At Date Id" = current_date
and CMPS."Created Date Id" > current_date-365
group by 1;`

Comment: No I just want the output of last query

Comment: I updated the answer to use `awk` to find the query based on semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file that executes each query but only sends the output of the last one.

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -h... -u... -p... -e 'query1' > /dev/null

mysql -h... -u... -p... -e 'query2' > /dev/null

mysql -h... -u... -p... -e 'query3' > /result.sql
```